# Load json file inside webpack config

Tags: json, webpack

I'm trying to import `json` file and use it as js object inside `webpack.config.js`:

```
const config = require("json-loader!./config.json");
```

but i get:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'json-loader!./config.json'
```

What's the tactic here? What's the preferred way to load config files inside Webpack?

Comment: maybe you have to use the import syntax?: import {something) from ..

Comment: nah, everything in my webpack.config is with require